# Python Json from Ordered Dict

Tags: python, json, ordereddictionary

I am tryinging to create a nested Json structure as follows:

Example Json:

```
      {
        "id" : "de",
        "Key" : "1234567",
        "from" : "test@test.com",
        "expires" : "2018-04-25 18:45:48.3166159",
        "command" : "method.exec",
        "params" : {
          "method" : "cmd",
          "Key" : "default",
          "params" : {
            "command" : "testing 23"
          }
        }
```

I am trying to do this from an OrderedDict. I am not sure of the correct way to structure the OrderedDict so that the correct Json is produced.

Python Code:

```
json_payload = OrderedDict(
                            [('id', id),
                                ('Key', keystore),
                                ('from', 'test@test.com'),
                                ('expires', expires),
                                ('command', 'method.exec')]

                              # What goes here for the params section??
                           )
print json.dumps(json_payload, indent=4, default=str)
```

Comment: `("params", OrderedDict([..., ("params", OrderedDict([("command", "testing 23")]))]))`

Answer (score 5):

Using @haifzhan's output as the input delivered exactly what was required.

```
 payload = OrderedDict(
      [
        ('id', 'de'), 
        ('Key', '1234567'), 
        ('from', 'test@test.com'), 
        ('expires', '2018-04-25 18:45:48.3166159'), 
        ('command', 'method.exec'), 
        ('params', 
          OrderedDict(
            [
              ('method', 'cmd'), 
              ('Key', 'default'),
              ('params', 
                OrderedDict(
                  [
                   ('command', 'testing 23')
                  ]
                )
              )
            ]
          )
        )
      ]
    )
print json.dumps(json_payload, indent=4, default=str)
```

Answer (score 4):

You missed a `}` at the end of your JSON data.

```
import json
import collections

data =  {
        "id" : "de",
        "Key" : "1234567",
        "from" : "test@test.com",
        "expires" : "2018-04-25 18:45:48.3166159",
        "command" : "method.exec",
        "params" : {
          "method" : "cmd",
          "Key" : "default",
          "params" : {
            "command" : "testing 23"
          }
        }}

data_str = json.dumps(data)
result = json.loads(data_str, object_pairs_hook=collections.OrderedDict)
print(result)
```

Output:

```
OrderedDict(
  [
    ('id', 'de'), 
    ('Key', '1234567'), 
    ('from', 'test@test.com'), 
    ('expires', '2018-04-25 18:45:48.3166159'), 
    ('command', 'method.exec'), 
    ('params', 
      OrderedDict(
        [
          ('method', 'cmd'), 
          ('Key', 'default'),
          ('params', 
            OrderedDict(
              [
               ('command', 'testing 23')
              ]
            )
          )
        ]
      )
    )
  ]
)
```

Answer (score 2):

A few things. `id` is a keyword. You can just pass a dictionary as a parameter.

```
ids = "de"
keystore = "1234567"
expires = "2018-04-25 18:45:48.3166159"
pdict = {
          "method" : "cmd",
          "Key" : "default",
          "params" : {
            "command" : "testing 23"
                     }
         }
json_payload = OrderedDict(
                            [('id', id),
                                ('Key', keystore),
                                ('from', 'test@test.com'),
                                ('expires', expires),
                                ('command', 'method.exec'),
                                ('params',pdict )
                            ]
                           )
print(json.dumps(json_payload, indent=4, default=str))
```

Answer (score 2):

**WORKING !!!**
Mostly When We serialize querysets instead of model instances
Ex :

```
serialized_data = SnippetSerializer(MyModel.objects.all(), many=True)
```

Output :

```
[
OrderedDict([('code', 'ABC'),  ('quantity', 5.0)]),
OrderedDict([('code', 'GGG'), ('quantity', 4.0)])
]
```

We can convert it to json like this : -

```
from rest_framework.renderers import JSONRenderer
from rest_framework.parsers import JSONParser
import io
result = JSONRenderer().render(serialized_data)
output_stream = io.BytesIO(result)
data = JSONParser().parse(output_stream)
print(data)
```

Output :

```
 [
    {'code': 'ABC', 'quantity': 5.0}, 
    {'code': 'GGG', 'quantity': 4.0}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the answer from [@Nids Barthwal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5157438/nids-barthwal) I was able to get around limitations of the json_script template tag.  I used that JSONRenderer strategy to create a custom tag:

```
@register.filter(name='ordereddict_to_json')
def ordereddict_to_json(value):
    result = JSONRenderer().render(value)
    output_stream = io.BytesIO(result)
    data = JSONParser().parse(output_stream)
    return json.dumps(data)
```

... once I plugged it into a data attribute...

```
<div id="foo" data-datavalue='{{ contextThing|ordereddict_to_json }}'>
    //  Something dynamically rendered in javascript
</div>
```

... it was easy to pick it up on the front end:

```
function renderMyThing(thing) {
    let dataValue = thing.data("datavalue")
    let htmlString = `This part: ${dataValue.something} and also this other part: ${dataValue.somethingElse}`
    
    // ...
}
```